# Different style when listing nodes and displaying a single node

Tags: drupal-7

I'm new at Drupal, coming from the PHP framework world, and I'm having some problems understanding the the template hierarchy in Drupal 7.

I've created a template called 'node--article.tpl.php' and can style my single article nodes. The problem is that this affects the front page as well. I want to style the node list different then when displaying single nodes. How can I do this?

/ Tobias

Answer (score 0):

The front page lists nodes that are flagged to be promoted to the front page.  You can flag/unflag each node in the Publishing Settings section of the node add/edit form.

Drupal provides a $promote variable that is available in the node template.  So, you can use that in node--article.tpl.php when determining what content you want to output:

```
if($promote) {
   print "<h2>".$title."</h2>"; 
} else {  
   print "<h1>".$title."</h1>";
}
```

If you need to get more complex in determining which nodes should be listed on the frontpage, you might want to look into the Views module: http://drupal.org/project/views.